# Sending console output to multiple writers

Tags: c#

I have an application that needs to redirect the output to Console.Write and Console.Writeline to somewhere else.

To elaborate further, my code starts a process at certain intervals. This proces is not written by me, or the company I work for, and I do not have source-code access.
I capture that output from that process because I need to know when I check up on the logs later if something has failed, and stuff like that, so I've redirected the output to a text-file like this:

```
String filename = "the-log-file-with-a-datetime-stamp.txt";
FileStream filestream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream);
streamwriter.AutoFlush = true;
Console.SetOut(streamwriter);
Console.SetError(streamwriter);
```

That works fine, sort of, but I would like to be able to redirect to more than one place, like I know redirect to a streamwriter.

Lets say for arguments sake I want it to redirect to the streamwriter AND write the line in a table in a database, and also show it in console, should someone have manually run the program.
How would I go about that?

Can I implement my own TextWriter and handle it there, and if so, how?

Please let me know if I can clarify further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to do as you suggested and write your own `TextWriter`-derived class. You could then use it to write to multiple other `TextWriter` instances.

[Documentation for TextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx) says, in its "Notes to inheritors":

> A derived class must minimally implement the TextWriter.Write(Char) method to make a useful instance of TextWriter.

So your derived `TextWriter` class would look something like:

```
public class MultiTextWriter: TextWriter
{
    private List<TextWriter> _writers = new List<TextWriter>();

    public void AddWriter(TextWriter writer)
    {
        _writers.Add(writer);
    }

    public override void Write(char ch)
    {
        foreach (var writer in _writers)
        {
            try
            {
                writer.Write(ch);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                // handle exception here
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                // handle exception here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And to use it...

```
MultiTextWriter Writer = new MultiTextWriter();
StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter(...);
StreamWriter sw2 = new StreamWriter(...);
Writer.AddWriter(sw1);
Writer.AddWriter(sw2);

Console.SetOut(Writer);
Console.SetError(Writer);
```

Note that my class and examples are pretty minimal. In particular, you'll need to add code that closes the individual streams. And you'll have to decide how you want to handle write errors.

You can override other `TextWriter` write methods if you want to potentially get better performance, but it's quite possible that just overriding the `Write(char)` method will perform well enough. It will depend on how much data is going out and how many different destinations.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the output to a MemoryStream, and monitor it (cycle+sleep). Upon arrival of data, send it to wherever you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `CompositeStream` class derived from the [`Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) class which will support only writing. And in overridden [`Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.write.aspx) method you can write to any number of underlying streams.

Answer (score 0):

Example of solution: Write your own class that derives from TextWriter which will echo the output to a StreamWriter and your other place.